# Unpacking Error: The product did not unpack correctly. Please download the product again

Tags: windows, dreamspark

I am trying to download Windows 7 from Dream Spark, student edition. I keep getting this error message:

> Unpacking Error: The product did not unpack correctly. Please download the product again.

Comment: Did you download the product again?

Comment: @DanielRHicks lol. try unpacking as adminsitrator.

Answer (score 1):

I did try again and again but was unsuccessful. So I performed some maintenance on my computer and remove any program that I did not want and tried again.  I am happy to report that I was able to download it.  Only thing is that I don't know exactly what solve the problem.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same Unpacking problem. You need to read the instructions properly, like I didn't at first. You must burn the .iso file onto a disc as a **DVD Format**! Then just run the setup of the disk and Windows 8 works fine

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, after two unsuccessful attempts, for me was to make sure there were not any interruptions or pauses from the beginning until the end. It then worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that downloading from DreamSpark has a lot of problems.

Try re-downloading the file again and, better solution, downloading it using an US proxy (if you're outside USA)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msdnfeedback/thread/d9415cb8-f160-40b5-bb00-6c5d7179591e

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, WITHOUT needing to redownload

1. while download manager is open, right click it on the taskbar
2. right click Shortcut to SecureDownloadManager.exe,
    click compatibility
3. click run this program as administrator
4. close and reopen download manager
5. click resume and it should instantly say unpacking!!! 

   shame on you microsoft for stuffing up your own programs on your own OS.

Comment: If you edit your post, and number the steps (`1.`), it will format very nicely. See the formatting help for more details.